# Is there a physical cause of uncertainty?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, error-analysis, observables

The [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) is confusing me. Considering this image from the article: [image: Position x and momentum p wavefunctions corresponding to quantum particles. The colour opacity of the particles corresponds to the probability density of finding the particle with position x or momentum component p. Top: If wavelength λ is unknown, so are momentum p, wave-vector k and energy E (de Broglie relations). As the particle is more localized in position space, Δx is smaller than for Δpx. Bottom: If λ is known, so are p, k, and E. As the particle is more localized in momentum space, Δp is smaller than for Δx.]

Is the particle believed to be physically moving with similar capriciousness in real space; and if so, what physically causes it to do so? (Some fundamental property of nature, a result thereof at small scales, the high energy of the particle, etc.)?

Or is this just an expression of what we can know when measuring?

Comment: You can formally derive the uncertainty principle from more fundamental principles in a variety of ways. (Search for "derivation of uncertainty principle" or consult your nearest introductory quantum mechanics textbook. I know Griffiths has a few pages dedicated to a derivation.) It'll just look like some guesses about arbitrary rules that things in the universe follow and lots of obtuse math, not an explanation in terms of things that are familiar from everyday experience, though.

Comment: Thanks, though deriving it from other terms is what I'm trying to avoid, rather, trying to understand it purely as a physical circumstance. What if known, would be the physical phenomena producing it, (especially for particles)? If the answer is "we don't know yet," that would be fine of course, but any work being done on that would also be helpful if able to point me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to see quantumness of small scale systems not as weird as they first seem, because most of them can be understood from a wave perspective.

Regarding the Uncertainty Principle and the impossibility of measure conjugate variables, like position and velocity, it also happen somehow in the classical world, let me explain myself:

Imagine an harmonic wave with a definite $k$ and $\omega$, then, add up a second wave with same $k$ and slightly different frequency which is coherent with the first one. The result is a superposed wave where certain max and mins are cancelled and with a less-defined frequency. If one adds infinite waves to the first one we will have a wave packet: an entity that is localised in space but not in the frequency domain. This is also known as a Fourier Transform in mathematics and it shows us how the localisation in space implies a spreading in frequency and viceversa, in the classical domains. Nevertheless, this doesn’t apply for particles where one can measure everything everywhere all at once.

Therefore, in quantum mechanics where the properties of particle and waves are mixed and combined, you will have the same uncertainty principle. The real quantumness of the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle is that there exists a fundamental limit in the relation between the uncertainties, while in classical mechanics $\Delta x \Delta p = 0$, in quantum mechanics it must be always greater than a quantum scale, i.e. $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$, meaning that it is impossible to measure both variables with 100% of accuracy.

The physical solutions to the Schrodinger equation are those that can be normalized in space, thus, the free wave is not a real solution due to $\Delta x = \infty$ and $\Delta p = 0$. In that case, physicists use the quantum fourier transform to build a wave packet that is normalizable in the Hilbert space, making the solution to fulfill the uncertainty relations inevitably.

This video can be useful to you to understand what is purely classical in the uncertainty principle:
https://youtu.be/MBnnXbOM5S4?si=SZIABAtDy3ZLj6Mt

T.

Comment: Thanks that video was fantastic! Very helpful to see it in the classical sense and how it still applies there. That answers that part of my question, but now taking that back to the part of my question re: quantum realm and some natural property; is it mainly because the speed of our observations relative to how fast particles "move" can't give us enough time to observe the particle as clearly? Or, just bc of how our models handle movement and time? Both? Or is there a physical trait about the universe itself which is intrinsically "pending further exchange such as measurement?"

Comment: Glad you enjoy the video! 3blue1brown channel is amazing! Back to your question, no there is not because the speed of our measurements, take a look to Quantum Zeno Effect where experimentalists try to measure quantum systems very fast in order to see the collapse of the wavefunction. As seen in the video, it is a matter of the wave behaviour of quantum systems. Even without observers the uncertainty principle is still there arising from the statistical properties of the wave functions. And also, even with a Galinean or Einstenian models of movement and time.

Comment: Fascinating. So do I understand it correctly then to summarize that "yes, uncertainty is thought to have an 'objective' physical cause in real nature beyond our models; which is the fluctuating behavior of waves as they move in spacetime or their relevant fields" ?

(To the limited extent that we can consider anything as "objective" beyond models).

Comment: Exactly! I will say so, at least... Quantum mechanics put in doubt the concept of absolute observer due to the measurement problem, to know, the non-unitary evolution of quantum states to go from a superposed state to the state observed. In Classical mechanics the observer is an objective entity that can measure without altering the system, but in Quantum mechanics observers affect the systems and its evolution. Nevertheless, even though the uncertainty principle is about measure and its seems to be kind of subjective, this fundamental property of wavefunctions is still there.

Answer (score 2):

Quantum theory describes a measurable quantity $A$ with an operator $\hat{A}$ called an observable. The expectation value of an observable is calculated using the system's state $\rho$, which is represented by a Hermitian operator with a trace of 1 with the formula $tr(\rho)\hat{A}=\sum_ip_ia_i$, where the $a_i$s are the possible values of $A$ and the $p_i$s are the probabilities. For some states and observables $p_i=1$ for one of the possible values and the observable $\hat{A}$ is said to be sharp and we see the same value when that observable is measured in that state, otherwise it is said to be unsharp. Not all of the observables of a system can be sharp at the same time and there are various ways of quantifying this:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04857

This uncertainty can't be eliminated according to quantum theory.

You write:

> why at Newtonian & relativistic scales can we say we know both speed and position together?

This is misleading. The scale of quantum uncertainty is roughly that the spreads of position and momentum  are related by $\Delta x\Delta p>\hbar/2\approx 3.3\times 10^{-34}Js$. So if $\Delta x$ was the size of an atom $10^{-10}m$, then $\Delta p>3.3\times 10^{-24}kgms^{-1}$, which you can't see with the naked eye. So the uncertainty principle is entirely consistent with what you see in everyday life.

This isn't quite the whole story of why the world looks roughly classical because if a narrow wavepacket was sent down two or more different paths it could still undergo interference and even for large objects this would be measurable in principle. The reason why you don't see quantum phenomena like interference in everyday life is that when information is copied out of a quantum system that suppresses interference in a process called decoherence:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282